# Is there a non blocking method for host resolution in WINAPI?

Tags: winapi, sockets, dns, nonblocking, getaddrinfo-a

There's [`getaddrinfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for blocking host resolution, but is there a non blocking method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is such a thing but you can always wrap it in a thread and use a semaphore to signal completion.

Answer (score 3):

Linux has [`getaddrinfo_a()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo_a). See the StackOverflow tag [getaddrinfo-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getaddrinfo-a), such as [this question "How to use getaddrinfo_a to do async resolve with glibc"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58069/60075). But I guess this isn't applicable for Windows.

There is a cross-platform library [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) for asynchronous DNS requests, which says it runs on Windows. (I haven't tried it myself.)

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN page on **[GetAddrInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfoexw)** the `OVERLAPPED` parameter says:

> On Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 or earlier, this parameter is currently reserved and must be set to **NULL** since asynchronous operations are not supported.

This means you can only use the `OVERLAPPED` function in Windows 8 and newer.  Unless steve can show otherwise that it works in older version of windows...

Comment: And to add further insult, [WSAConnectByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaconnectbynamea) (the function Microsoft [recommends be used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/function-calls-2) to establish protocol agnostic outgoing connections) has an `OVERLAPPED` parameter, but it is *"Reserved for future implementation. This parameter must be set to **NULL**."*

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 you can use [GetAddrInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with an [OVERLAPPED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

Once the `hEvent` event is set in the `OVERLAPPED` structure use [GetAddrInfoExOverlappedResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448783%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).